# How to use Nginx unit with ws package in node js

Tags: ws

I've set up an http server that can receive rest and websocket requests using the following code
It works fine when I launch the server via node, but if I launch the server with ngnix unit the server launches but I can't receive data via my socket.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Websocket = require('ws');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080
assert.ok(process.env.WS_SERVER, 'You must define the WS_SERVER env variable');
console.log(`setting up record path at ${process.env.WS_SERVER }`);

//
async function handleUpload(socket) {

    socket._recvInitialMetadata = false;
    socket.on('message', function(data, isBinary) {
      console.log(data)
      if(socket._recvInitialMetadata) return
      socket._recvInitialMetadata = true
    });

    socket.on('error', function(err) {
      console.error({err}, 'stream upload: error');
    });
    socket.on('close', (data) => {
      console.info({data}, 'stream: close');
    });
    socket.on('end', function(err) {
      console.error({err}, 'stream upload: socket closed');
    });
}

// Config webServer
const wsServer = new Websocket.Server({ noServer: true });
wsServer.setMaxListeners(0);
wsServer.on('connection', handleUpload.bind(null));

// Config Express
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  logger.error(err, 'burped error');
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({msg: err.message});
});

const server = app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  if(head === undefined) head = new Uint8Array() // Fix here cause ngnix-unit pass head value to undefined
  wsServer.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (socket) => {
    if (request.url !== process.env.WS_SERVER) return socket.destroy();
    wsServer.emit('connection', socket, request);
  });
});

var unitSocketServer = undefined
try {
  require.resolve('unit-http')
  unitSocketServer = require('unit-http/websocket').server({httpServer : server})
  console.log('unit-http websocket server is loaded')
} catch {

}
```

Here my ngnix-unit configuration (I'm using the 1.29 v)

```
{
    "listeners": {
        "*:8080": {
            "pass": "applications/app-test"
        }
    },
    "applications": {
        "app-test": {
            "type": "external",
            "working_directory": "/var/www/app",
            "executable": "/usr/bin/env",
            "user": "www-data",
            "group": "www-data",
            "arguments": [
                "node",
                "--loader",
                "unit-http/loader.mjs",
                "--require",
                "unit-http/loader",
                "app.js"
            ],
            "processes": {
                "max" : 12,
                "spare" : 3,
                "idle_timeout" : 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```